# How to avoid seeing bottom two bars at google.com, the ones that say "United Kingdom" and "Advertising" etc.?

Tags: google-search

When I browse to google.com I get a bar at the bottom saying "United Kingdom" and another saying "Advertising" "Business", "How Search Works", "Privacy", "Terms", "Settings". How can I avoid seeing these two bars? At the moment I get them using both Firefox and Internet Explorer.

In response to @Ruben's comments: in order to investigate the above-mentioned research question I made enquiries using websearch engines supplied by a number of companies including DuckDuckGo and Alphabet (owner of the "Google" brand), but to no avail. I hope this information makes it easier for readers to assist with answering the research question regarding how to avoid seeing the referenced bottom bars when browsing to the referenced webpage.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Just like @Rubén said. In any case, you could use some custom css or an adblocker.

Comment: @marikamitsos - An adblocker wouldn't work, and there must be an easier way than writing some custom CSS in order to prevent annoying bars referencing a monarchy and commercial conditioning activities from showing up at the bottom of one particular webpage.